# Adding specific numbers within an Array

Tags: java, arrays, sum

For my project, I am creating an excel spreadsheet with several functions. I am currently trying to implement a sum algorithm that takes in an input from a user and calculates the sum within the array that the user wants.

For example when a user types in the console:

A1 = 3

A2 = 2

A3 = 1

A4 = ( sum A1 - C1 )

The cells of each will have its respected values and A4 will contain the sum of A1 through C1, which in this case be six. My current code contains the values of cells A1 through C1 into an array. Here is the code which I'm trying to implement the calculations for my spreadsheet.

```
public String eval (Sheet sheet) {
        String stuff = string.substring(2, string.length() - 2);
        String [] arr = stuff.split(" ");
        if (arr[0].equals("sum")) {
            Double total = 0.0;
            String alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            String tempFirst = arr[1].substring(0, 1);
            String tempSecond = arr[3].substring(0, 1);
            int firstColumn = alph.indexOf(tempFirst);
            int secondColumn = alph.indexOf(tempSecond);
            int firstRow = Integer.valueOf(arr[1].substring(1));
            int secondRow = Integer.valueOf(arr[3].substring(1));
            if (firstColumn == secondColumn) {
                for (int i = firstRow; i <= secondRow; i++) {
                    for (int j = firstColumn; j <= secondColumn; j++) {
                        total += Double.valueOf(sheet.referenceTwo(i, j));

                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
            arr[i] = sheet.referenceOne(arr[i]);
        }
        Double total = Double.valueOf(arr[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
            if (arr[i].equals("*")) {
                 total = total * Double.valueOf(arr[i+1]);
            }
            else if (arr[i].equals("+")) {
                total = total + Double.valueOf(arr[i+1]);
            }
            else if (arr[i].equals("-")) {
                total = total - Double.valueOf(arr[i+1]);
            }
            else if (arr[i].equals("/")) {
                total = total / Double.valueOf(arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
        return total + "";
    }
```

For this part of my code, it passes in user input, which in this case will be sum A1 - C1. Then it stores it into an array that divides it by the spaces. If the array contains "sum", it will go through the following code. It parses the A1 and C1 and gets the row and column position of the array. For example, for A1, the position would be (0, 0) in the array. It will then use the sheetReferenceTwo method that is in another part of my code that returns the value of the location in the array.

Here are the codes for my methods that figures out the info within the array

```
public String referenceOne (String location) {
    String temp = location.substring(0, 1);
    int letter = alph.indexOf(temp);
    int num = Integer.valueOf(location.substring(1, 2)) - 1;
    return contents[num][letter].eval(this);

}

public String referenceTwo (int row, int col) {
    return contents[row][col].eval(this);
}
```

For some reason I'm getting a

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "u"

And it stops at Sheet.referenceOne(Sheet.java:41)

I'm currently stuck on what to do to implement this and would like some advice.

Comment: Please post the complete Stack Trace

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arr[0].equals("sum")) {
....
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    arr[i] = sheet.referenceOne(arr[i]);
}
```

In reference to the above code, consider the case in which `arr[0]` is equal to `"sum"`. The code will enter the `referenceOne` method passing this value:

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(location.substring(1, 2)) - 1;
```

This will cause a `NumberFormatException` (it is essentially calling `Integer.valueOf("u")`). Pass only the appropriate array elements you wish to pass to `referenceOne`.

Comment: The referenceOne method is intended to just add the numbers if the user input just contained specific calls to the cells. For example A4 = ( A1 - A3 ) would have the value of -2. In my if (arr[0].equals("sum")) {, this is where it  tries to calculate the sum. How can I make it that it ignores the lower part of the code? I'm somewhat confused to this as this is my first year of computer science.

Comment: You might consider initializing the loop referenced in my answer at 1 index (rather than 0), presuming the input is `( sum A1 - C1 )` the array would contain {"sum", "A1", "-", "C1"}, and you wish to evaluate index 1 and 3 (?)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider writing a parser and proper expression evaluator rather than picking out first and second characters from the input. I think half your problem is not clearly processing the command lines.

IOW write classes like Token, Variable, Number, Expression, etc. and have them process an object like Spreadsheet.